# Vercel: installing github repositories as package not working

Tags: python, flask, vercel

My flask application works locally but I cannot get it working on vercel. I get the following errors:

> Warning: Python version "3.10" detected in Pipfile.lock is invalid and will be ignored. http://vercel.link/python-version

> Failed to run "pip3.9 install --disable-pip-version-check --target . --upgrade -r /vercel/path0/requirements.txt"
> Error: Command failed: pip3.9 install --disable-pip-version-check --target . --upgrade -r /vercel/path0/requirements.txt

> ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'git+git+https://github.com/account/application_to_install_as_package@16198103#egg=application_to_install_as_package' (from line 46 of /vercel/path0/requirements.txt)
> Hint: It looks like a path. File 'git+git+https://github.com/account/application_to_install_as_package@16198103...#egg=application_to_install_as_package' does not exist.

I forked https://vercel.com/templates/python/flask-hello-world and it worked.  I then added the package I need, and same errors.

I'm using python 3.10 on WSL (I tried both windows 11 and WSL, both same issues)

The package is public and not private.

Is there anything I can do to make this work on vercel?

Comment: Could you show the parts of your requirements file where you specify the package? `git+git+...` and `...github.com/account...` don't look like a valid source.

Comment: And Vercel now [lists only version 3.9](https://vercel.com/docs/functions/serverless-functions/runtimes/python#python-version) as available. Maybe you need to downgrade?

Comment: @Dmitry git+https://github.com/account/repo.git ...it's working locally too which i don't understand.  I tried to install using python 3.9 as well and same error.  Have you ever used this style of installing using the "git+" method? on vercel

Comment: similar issue is happening on elastic beanstalk but the error is: `ERROR: Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'git' while executing command git version
ERROR: Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?` -  i have git installed as well.  tried from WSL2, gitbash, and windows.  moved git to C and D.  all the same error.  i cant seem to figure out what im doing wrong